# Angular Ionic 3 input stay focus on the password field when the eye icon is clicked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, input, passwords, ionic3

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I have a **login form** with email and password input field. My **password field** has an **eye-icon** that has a `method` that shows the password as a text or hide it vice versa when **tapped**.

Here is my code in my **html**

```
<ion-input #pwInput class="input-cover" [type]="type" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required class="input-password">
            </ion-input>
            <ion-icon (tap)="showPassword()" [name]="type == 'password' ? 'app-svg-eye-show' : 'app-svg-eye-close'" class="eye-icon"></ion-icon>
```

and in my **ts file**

```
type: any = 'password' // Password type be default

showPassword() {
    this.showPass = !this.showPass;
    if (this.showPass) {
      this.type = 'text';
    } else {
      this.type = 'password';
    }
  }
```

Now the method is working fine for displaying password or text in an **ngModel**. However when I tested it on my Android device when the **small icon** is **tapped** to display the password the focus loses on the password input field and the keyboard goes down.

What I want to happen is to stay focus on the password input field even if the small icon is tapped.

How can I make it not lose focus on the password field?

I tried to use `setFocus()` on the `viewChild` but it causes some flickering effect on the device which is bad.

appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try autofocus html attribute

Comment: also (blind bet) did you try: (tap)="showPassword(); pwInput.setFocus()"?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko that didn't work for me

Comment: sec I will try something (a trick) if no one helps you here I will post it in 10 min